# Adding an image in place of a button in html javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, grails

The problem is : 
I have "+" and "-" at the end of the row to add and delete rows accordingly.

Instead of "-" icon, I want to replace a trashbox.. I tried replacing with imgsrc. But it skews the alignment.

Even if we remove the box from the "+" and keep the + alone for adding row and delete trashbox for "-", it would be great.

Can anyone help me out with this? Code below.

```
 <tr>
                <td align="left">
                <g:select name="standard[]" id="standard" class="statSele valid" from="${standardList}" value="" noSelection="['':'Select Regulatory Standard...']"/>
                <g:select name="standard_version[]" id="standard_version" class="statSele valid" from="${standardversion}" value="" noSelection="['':'Select Version...']" style="width:150px !important;"/>
                <g:select name="standard_domainnumbers[]" id="standard_domainnumbers" req="false" class="statSeledomain valid" from="${['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48','49','50']}" value="" noSelection="['':'Select Domain...']"/>
                <INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk" class="delCheck"/>
                <input type="button" value=" + " title="Add More" class="clone-faculty"/>
                <input type="button" value=" - " title="Remove selected Row" class="remove-faculty"/>
                </td>
            </tr>


    <script>
         $('.clone-faculty').click(function() {  
            var clone = $('.add-child:first').clone(true).appendTo('#itemRows');        
            });

         $(".remove-faculty").click(function(e) {

             if($('.add-child').length > 1)
             {
                 if($(".delCheck:checked").length != $('.add-child').length)
                 {
                  $(".delCheck:checked").closest("table").remove();
                  // $(".add-child").last().remove();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     alert('You cannot delete all rows.');
                 }
             }
          });
        </script>
```

Comment: Please replicate your problem in [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Not clear with your problem . If you are struggling with alignment than use the another table inside <td align="left"> & keep 1 tr row and 6 td ( 1td for one control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
<td align="left">
        <g:select name="standard[]" id="standard" class="statSele valid" from="${standardList}" value="" noSelection="['':'Select Regulatory Standard...']" />
        <g:select name="standard_version[]" id="standard_version" class="statSele valid" from="${standardversion}" value="" noSelection="['':'Select Version...']" style="width:150px !important;" />
        <g:select name="standard_domainnumbers[]" id="standard_domainnumbers" req="false" class="statSeledomain valid" from="${['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48','49','50']}" value="" noSelection="['':'Select Domain...']" />
        <INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk" class="delCheck" />
        <input type="button" value=" + " title="Add More" class="clone-faculty" />

        <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/trash.png" style="width:17px;vertical-align: middle;" title="Remove selected Row" class="remove-faculty">
    </td>
```

[Here is the JSFiddle of how it looks](https://jsfiddle.net/ceoe8k4f/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 <tr>
                <td align="left">
                <g:select name="standard[]" id="standard" class="statSele valid" from="${standardList}" value="" noSelection="['':'Select Regulatory Standard...']"/>
                <g:select name="standard_version[]" id="standard_version" class="statSele valid" from="${standardversion}" value="" noSelection="['':'Select Version...']" style="width:150px !important;"/>
                <g:select name="standard_domainnumbers[]" id="standard_domainnumbers" req="false" class="statSeledomain valid" from="${['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48','49','50']}" value="" noSelection="['':'Select Domain...']"/>
                <INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk" class="delCheck"/>

                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-add" ng-click=""></span>

                <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ng-click=""></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" value=" + " title="Add More" class="clone-faculty"/>
<input type="button" value=" - " title="Remove selected Row" class="remove-faculty"/>
```

is replace with following code

```
<img  src=" + src " width="what size you want" title="Add More" class="clone-faculty"/>
<img  value=" - src" width="what size you want" title="Remove selected Row" class="remove-faculty"/>
```

once the width attribute declared don't declare height value it will miss the ratio of your image